# Modifying the values of a variable within a data frame

Tags: r, loops, variables, dataframe

[Working with R 3.2.2]

I am trying to modify the values of several variables included in a data  frame using a loop. Specifically, I want to divide all the values of 11 variables by 10.

First, I tried to do it for one variable (bio1):

```
dataframe0$bio1/10
```

This command shows the result I want to obtain in the console, but it does not modify it in the data frame.

When trying to build the loop, I came up with some option:

First, I created a vector with all the variables and then I constructed the loop:

```
vlist <- c("bio1", "bio2", "bio3", "bio4", "bio5", "bio6", "bio7", "bio8", "bio9", "bio10", "bio11")
for (i in vlist) {
  dataframe0$i/10
}
```

Since the previous code is probably substituting the ´ ".." ´ as well as the string inside the loop (´i´) and, as a consequence, it does not work, I tried with this other loop:

```
for(var in paste0("bio", 1:11)) {
  dataframe0$var/10
}
```

What should I do in order to execute it and save the modifications in the data frame? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you could precise which programming language and which framework/libraries you are using. Add it in the tag section so people interested in these can find your answer easily and answer it.

Comment: @JeromeFr Thanks! I do not have libraries associated to these code...

Comment: try apply(dataframe0,2,function(x) x/10) or apply(dataframe0[,which(grepl("bio",names(datafram0)))],2,function(x) x/10)

Comment: @Leo P. It works! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution will probably be

```
dataframe0[,vlist] <- dataframe0[,vlist] / 10
```

A loop won't be necessary for this.

Example (using some of my own data for convenience):

```
> head(websurvey[,c("age", "dur")])
      age dur
17514  68 320
15091  70 503
18152  30 276
7558   39 311
22594  47 161
5108   56 284

> websurvey_test[,c("age", "dur")] <- websurvey[,c("age", "dur")]/10

> head(websurvey_test[,c("age", "dur")])
      age  dur
17514 6.8 32.0
15091 7.0 50.3
18152 3.0 27.6
7558  3.9 31.1
22594 4.7 16.1
5108  5.6 28.4
```